# Vuex. Again: Computed properties are not updated after Store changes. The simplest example

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I did really read all Google!

- Store property "sProp" HAS initial value (=10);
- I use Action from component to modify property;
- Action COMMITS mutation inside the Store Module;
- Mutation uses "Vue.set(..." as advised in many tickets
- Component uses mapState, mapGetters, mapActions (!!!)
- I also involve Vuex as advised.

I see initial state is 10. But it is not changed after I press button.
However if I console.log Store, I see it is changed. It also is changed in memory only once after the 1st press, but template always shows 10 for both variants. All the other presses do not change value.

**Issue: my Computed Property IS NOT REACTIVE!**

Consider the simplest example.File names are in comments.

```
// File: egStoreModule.js
import * as Vue    from "vue/dist/vue.js";

const state = {
    sProp:         10,
};

const getters   = {
    gProp: (state) => {
        return state.sProp;
    }
};
const mutations = {
    //generic(state, payload) {},
    mProp(state, v) {
        Vue.set(state, "sProp", v);
    },
};
const actions   = {
    aProp({commit}, v) {
        commit('mProp', v);
        return v;
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true
    , state
    , getters
    , mutations
    , actions
}
```

And it's comsumer:

```
// File: EgStoreModuleComponent.vue
<template>
    <!--<div :flag="flag">-->
    <div>
        <div><h1>{{sProp}} : mapped from Store</h1></div>
        <div><h1>{{$store.state.egStoreModule.sProp}} : direct from Store</h1></div>
        <button @click="methChangeProp">Change Prop</button>
        <button @click="log">log</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapActions, mapGetters, mapState} from "vuex";

    export default {
        name:     'EgStoreModuleComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                flag:      true,
            };
        },

        computed: {
            ...mapState('egStoreModule', ['sProp']),
            ...mapGetters('egStoreModule', ['gProp'])
        },

        methods: {
            ...mapActions('egStoreModule', ['aProp']),

            methChangeProp() {
                const value = this.sProp + 3;
                this.aProp(value);
                //this.flag = !this.flag;
            },

            log() {
                console.log("log ++++++++++");
                console.log(this.sProp);
            },
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Here is how I join the Store Module to Application:

```
// File: /src/store/index.js
import Vue           from 'vue'
import Vuex          from 'vuex'
import collection    from "./modules/collection";
import egStoreModule from "./modules/egStoreModule";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    getters : {},
    mutations: {},
    actions : {},
    modules : {
        collection,
        egStoreModule
    }
});
```

Finally: main.js

```
import Vuex       from 'vuex'
import {store}    from './store'
//...
new Vue({
    el:     '#app',
    router: router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
})
```

- It all works if only I use "flag" field as shown in comments.
- It also works if I jump from page and back with Vue-router.
- async/await does not help.
- I deleted all under node_modules and run npm install.
- All Vue/Vuex versions are the latest.

Comment: Have you tried using the mapState as follows?
...mapState({ sprop: state => state.egStoreModule.sProp

Comment: I tried running all this code myself and everything seemed to be working correctly, with the numbers increasing by 3 each time I clicked. I suggest adding console logging to your store to investigate further. My best guess would be that you aren't actually running the code you think you're running, e.g. an unsaved file or something like that.

Comment: I did really think about that. My nearest idea to create the newest default  project and  try everything from the scratch. May be this is not the worst way...

Comment: Often I find that when building out your problem in a fresh code sandbox you will stumble upon the answer. And if you don't, now you have some code to share with people to play with in order to help solve quicker than reading multiple code snippets.

Comment: Ha! Thank you )))

Comment: Well... I've tested on the clean sandbox project. IT WORKS!!! Now I'm going to check different dependencies: Bootstrap, Keen UI, etc... Ho-ho-ho-ho...